The complier is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time
struct RuArticle: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let dateCreated: Date?
    let ruTitle: String?
    let ruText: String?
    let ruDescription: String?
    let likesCount: Int?
    let isPremium: Bool?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case dateCreated = "date_created"
        case ruTitle = "ru_title"
        case ruText = "ru_text"
        case ruDescription = "ru_description"
        case likesCount = "likes_count"
        case isPremium = "is_premium"
    }
}

struct TopArticlesIndexes: Codable {
    let topArticlesIndexes: [String]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case topArticlesIndexes = "top_articles_indexes"
    }
}

struct MaxIndex: Codable {
    let maxIndex: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case maxIndex = "max_index"
    }
}

final class ArticlesManager {
    static let shared = ArticlesManager()
    private init() {}
    
    private let articlesCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("articles")
    
    private func articleDocument(id: String) -> DocumentReference {
        articlesCollection.document(id)
    }
    
    func getRuArticle(id: String) async throws -> RuArticle {
        try await articleDocument(id: id).getDocument(as: RuArticle.self)
    }
    
    func getEnArticle(id: String) async throws -> EnArticle {
        try await articleDocument(id: id).getDocument(as: EnArticle.self)
    }
    
    func getTopArticlesIndexes() async throws -> [String]? {
        let topArticlesIndexes = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("topArticlesIndexes").document("0").getDocument(as: TopArticlesIndexes.self)
        
        return topArticlesIndexes.topArticlesIndexes
    }
    
    func updateLikes(at articleId: String, likesCount: Int) async throws {
        let data: [String: Any] = [
            "likes_count": likesCount
        ]
        
        try await articleDocument(id: articleId).updateData(data)
    }
    
    func getAllEnArticles() async throws -> [EnArticle?] {
        let snapshot = try await articlesCollection.getDocuments()
        
        var articles: [EnArticle] = []
        
        for document in snapshot.documents {
            let article = try document.data(as: EnArticle.self)
            articles.append(article)
        }
        
        return articles
    }
    
    func getAllRuArticles() async throws -> [RuArticle?] {
        let snapshot = try await articlesCollection.getDocuments()
        
        var articles: [RuArticle] = []
        
        for document in snapshot.documents {
            let article = try document.data(as: RuArticle.self)
            articles.append(article)
        }
        
        return articles
    }
    
    func getMaxIndex() async throws -> String? {
        let maxIndex = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("maxIndex").document("0").getDocument(as: MaxIndex.self)
        
        return maxIndex.maxIndex
    }
}


@MainActor
final class EnLikedPostsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isReadViewPresented = false
    @Published var articles: [EnArticle?] = []
    @Published var likedPostsIndexes: [String] = []
    @Published var errorText = ""
    @Published var isErrorPopupPresented = false
    @Published var isDescriptionPopupPresented = false
    
    var description = ""
    var title = ""
    var image = UIImage()
    var dateCreated = Date()
    var text = ""
    var likesCount = 0
    var id = ""
    
    func loadLikedPosts() async throws {
        let authDataResult = try AuthenticationManager.shared.getAuthenticatedUser()
        let user = try await UserManager.shared.getUser(userId: authDataResult.uid)
        
        self.likedPostsIndexes = user.likedPosts ?? []
    }
    
    func getArticles() async throws {
        articles = []
        
        for index in likedPostsIndexes {
            do {
                articles.append(try await ArticlesManager.shared.getEnArticle(id: index))
            } catch {
                withAnimation {
                    errorText = "Article not found"
                    isErrorPopupPresented = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EnLikedPostsView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = EnLikedPostsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    if viewModel.articles == [] {
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 20) {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "list.bullet.below.rectangle")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                            
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey("noArticlesAddedLabel"))
                                .font(.title)
                                .bold()
                                .fontDesign(.rounded)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        }
                        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 200, alignment: .center)
                        
                    } else {
                        ForEach(viewModel.articles) { article in
                            if article != nil {
                                ArticleView(id: article.id, title: article.enTitle, isPremium: article.isPremium)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        viewModel.description = article.enDescription ?? "Not found"
                                        viewModel.title = article.enTitle ?? "Not found"
                                        viewModel.text =  article.enText ?? "Not found"
                                        viewModel.image = StorageManager.shared.getImage(id: article.id) ?? UIImage()
                                        viewModel.dateCreated = article.dateCreated ?? Date()
                                        viewModel.likesCount = article.likesCount ?? 0
                                        viewModel.id = article.id
                                        
                                        
                                        viewModel.isDescriptionPopupPresented = true
                                    }
                                    .padding(.top, 10)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .refreshable {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await viewModel.loadLikedPosts()
                        return
                    } catch {
                        withAnimation {
                            viewModel.errorText = error.localizedDescription
                        }
                    }
                    
                    viewModel.isErrorPopupPresented = true
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: viewModel.likedPostsIndexes, perform: { newValue in
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await viewModel.getArticles()
                        return
                    } catch {
                        viewModel.errorText = error.localizedDescription
                    }
                    
                    viewModel.isErrorPopupPresented = true
                }
            })
            .popup(isPresented: $viewModel.isDescriptionPopupPresented) {
                DescriptionView(
                    isReadViewPresented: $viewModel.isReadViewPresented,
                    description: viewModel.description
                )
                .shadow(radius: 3)
            } customize: {
                $0
                    .type(.toast)
                    .appearFrom(.bottomSlide)
                    .dragToDismiss(true)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.isReadViewPresented, content: {
                ReadView(
                    id: viewModel.id,
                    title: viewModel.title,
                    text: viewModel.text,
                    image: viewModel.image,
                    dateCreated: viewModel.dateCreated,
                    likesCount: viewModel.likesCount,
                    likedPosts: $viewModel.likedPostsIndexes
                    
                )
            })
            .popup(isPresented: $viewModel.isErrorPopupPresented) {
                Text(viewModel.errorText)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 72, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .padding(.vertical, 16)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                    .padding(.top, 20)
            } customize: {
                $0
                    .type(.floater())
                    .position(.top)
                    .animation(.bouncy)
                    .dragToDismiss(true)
                    .autohideIn(5)
            }
            .onAppear {
                if viewModel.likedPostsIndexes == [] {
                    Task {
                        do {
                            try await viewModel.loadLikedPosts()
                            return
                        } catch {
                            withAnimation {
                                viewModel.errorText = error.localizedDescription
                            }
                        }
                        
                        viewModel.isErrorPopupPresented = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
//                    Text(LocalizedStringKey("favoritesLabel"))
//                        .font(.largeTitle)
//                        .fontDesign(.rounded)
//                        .fontWeight(.light)
                    
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 130)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemBackground))
                            .padding(.bottom, 40)
                            .shadow(radius: 5)
                        
                        Text(LocalizedStringKey("favoritesLabel"))
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .fontDesign(.rounded)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 6)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Can you please tell me why it gives this error?
I tried to rewrite it, I removed the code with requests to the server, but it still gives this error... Moreover, it always outputs on different files. I have an identical screen that receives data in English and returns an error either in one language or the other.

When you get an error like that in your view code (I assume it's the view that generates the error) then the best way forward is to comment out part by part of the view until the error disappears to pinpoint the location of the error or the opposite and comment out everything and then uncomment part by part.

Sadly, that error is not very helpful. It essentially means "The compiler got confused." Worse, it can apply to an entire section of code, not just one line. As Joakim suggests, you usually have to work with blocks of code at a time, commenting them out until you find the section causing the problem.

One thing that sometimes helps is adding explicit types to your variables, closure parameters, and closure return values.

This error is always a typo in this case probably because of the optionals
